# Check two variables in js switch case

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 variables that return true and false. And I want each one that was false to return the corresponding text.
How to handle this ValidCheked and repeatChecked in the switch?

```
   export const checked = (e, options) => {
    
      const nameCheked = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,50}$");
    
      const repeatChecked = options.every(
        (pool) => pool.text.toLowerCase() !== e.target.value.toLowerCase()
      );
      const validCheked = nameCheked.test(e.target.value);
    
      switch (repeatChecked) {
        case true:
          return {
            type: true,
            text: "looks good"
          };
        case false:
          return {
            type: false,
            text: "repeatName"
          }
        case validCheked = true:
          return {
            type: true,
            text: "looks good"
          }
        case validCheked = false:
          return {
            type: true,
            text: "Invalid name (no special character)"
          }
        default:
          return {
            type: false,
            text: "looks good"
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Why should this be a `switch` and not an `if/else`? 2. When would you ever get to checking `validChecked` if `repeatChecked` can *only* be `true` or `false` and each one of these would return from the function?

Comment: When the user types and enters the input, the value is stored in the state and the condition is checked. Errors are displayed. I want the text of the errors to be different.

Comment: This answers precisely none of my two questions.

Comment: 1. Because I want to use it everywhere in the project and for other inputs. 2. If the user enters a duplicate name, repeadChecked will be checked, and if a special character uses @ $ #, it will be validchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use switch structure like this:

```
switch (true) {
 case (repeatChecked== true && validCheked == true):
   //do something (if you return something here, don't need to break;)
   break;
 case (repeatChecked== false && validCheked == false):
   //do something (if you return something here, don't need to break;)
   break;
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is not a good way to use `switch`.

Comment: What is the best way?